# Save Field Data in vtkUnstructuredGrid in VTK 8.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk

I am trying to save a vector field for a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` using `VTK 8.1` at the cell centers of a mesh of tetrahedrons. `unstructuredGrid1` is my unstructured grid pointer which is already populated with the definition of points and cells. My goal now is to add a field data to it.

My research online found that people are using the following to store the vectors in an unstructured grid:

```
unstructuredGrid1->GetPointData()->SetVectors(myvectors);
```

This should be able to save the vectors for my mesh. However, Visual Studio 2017 community edition complains about:

- pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
- use of undefined type '`vtkPointData`'

VS IntelliSense also does not show the available functions after I type `unstructuredGrid1->GetPointData()->`.

Could someone kindly help me how I can solve this issue? Is there any other way to store field data to a `vtkUnstructuredGrid`? Thank you.

Comment: `#include <vtkPointData.h>`

Comment: @AlexF That was it! It fixed the issue. Thank you.